# It is possible to issue java.lang.reflect.Field to javafx.scene.control.TextField?

Tags: javafx-8

It is possible to issue java.lang.reflect.Field to javafx.scene.control.TextField?

For example:

```
Field[] nodes;
nodes = clase.getDeclaredFields();

for (Field n : nodes)
   if (n.getType().getSimpleName().equals("TextField"))
     ((TextField)((Object) n)).setText("Text");
```

Comment: No: a `Field` is not a `TextField`, and never can be. (It can be of type `TextField`, but that does not mean the same thing.) What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I know that a Field is not a TextField. I am trying to get all the TextField of a form to modify some property, so that I try to do it with Reflection getting all the TextField declared in the Class.

Comment: If you already know that, why are you posting code where you try to cast a `Field` to a `TextField`? You know it is guaranteed to throw a `ClassCastException`. Why use reflection at all here? Why wouldn't you just call the method on each text field in the controller, in the usual way? You need to [edit] your question to explain what the actual problem is.

Comment: Ask why the best someone could have done something like that, get and modify the properties of a Field. The problem is that there are many TextFields inside the form, so I was thinking of a way to get them all and modify them all at once, without needing to do it one by one.

Comment: Like I said, [edit] your question to explain the actual problem you are trying to solve. This just looks like an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If there are so many text fields, then it would seem to have made sense to defined them in a loop anyway: why not just process them in a similar loop?

Comment: My question is how to get all TextFields from a JavaFX form to modify them.

Comment: What is a JavaFX form? There is no such predefined control or component, so it depends entirely on how you have created this. Generally (because you haven't given any specific details), you would just put the text fields in an array or list when you create them, and then you can iterate through that array or list and call whatever methods on them you need to modify them. (Obviously if you were just changing the style, you would use CSS, but your example calls `setText(...)`.)

Comment: That is the problem as there are many TextFields inside the form, it is tedious to introduce them all inside a array or list. For that I would like to find an easier way to get them all.

Comment: So why don't you do what I suggested, and put them in the list when you create them? That way it will take almost no additional code.

Comment: It is possible!!!!                        
http://stackoverflow.com/a/43787638/7110383

Answer (score 1):

If you want to modify the `TextField`s, you need to retrieve the value from those fields (and cast this value to `TextField`).

The following example should demonstrate the approach:

```
private TextField t1 = new TextField();
private TextField t2 = new TextField();

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Button btn = new Button("Say 'Hello World'");
    btn.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
        Object object = this;
        Class clazz = object.getClass();
        for (Field field : clazz.getDeclaredFields()) {
            if (field.getType().getName().equals("javafx.scene.control.TextField")) {
                try {
                    // get field value here
                    TextField textField = (TextField) field.get(object);

                    if (textField != null) {
                        textField.setText("Hello World");
                    }
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(ReflectTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }

    });

    VBox root = new VBox();
    root.getChildren().addAll(btn, t1, t2);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. James_D told me that I was crazy and that you could not do that ever, convert a java.lang.reflect.Field to javafx.scene.control.TextField. Thank you very much again.

Comment: @R3ing I said you couldn't assign a `Field` to a `TextField`: you can't - you have to retrieve the value from it as in this answer. But I argued (and still argue) that there is no point in this approach: if there are so many text fields that an approach like this is worth considering, then presumably you do not want to declare them all individually as fields anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Reflection is probably a really bad approach to this. Among many problems is that you make the functionality dependent on *how the code is written*. Specifically, you assume that each text field is stored in a specific instance field in some class. If you change the implementation, e.g. so that you keep the text fields in a data structure instead of maintaining references to them yourself, then your functionality will break. It is bad practice to write code that is so tightly coupled to the actual implementation of the code, for obvious reasons.

One better approach would simply to be to put all the text fields in a list (or other data structure), so you can do whatever you need with them easily. E.g.

```
public class MyForm {

    private GridPane view ;

    private String[] messages = {"First name:", "Last name", "Email"} ;

    private List<TextField> textFields ;

    public MyForm {

        view = new GridPane();
        textFields = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int r = 0; r < messages.length ; r++) {
            view.addRow(r, new Label(messages[r]), createTextField(messages[r]));
        }
    }

    private TextField createTextField(String text) {
        TextField textField = new TextField();
        textField.setPromptText(text);
        textFields.add(textField);
        return textField ;
    }

    public void processTextFields() {
        textField.forEach(tf -> tf.setText("Hello"));
    }
}
```

Another approach would be to use a CSS lookup. If `myForm` is some node that is an ancestor of all the text fields:

```
myForm.lookupAll(".text-field").forEach(node -> {
    TextField textField = (TextField)node ;
    textField.setText("Hello");
});
```

but note that CSS lookups will not work until after CSS has been applied (by default, this means after the scene has been rendered for the first time).

Another way, if all the text fields are all contained in a single direct parent (such as the grid pane in the first example), would be to iterate through the child nodes and filter the text fields:

```
textFieldParentNode.getChildrenUnmodifiable().stream()
    .filter(TextField.class::isInstance)
    .map(TextField.class::cast)
    .forEach(tf -> tf.setText("Hello"));
```